# Send Outlook Template Through Python

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I have the following code to send an email to a specified recipient, but the email that I am trying to send is standard, long, and formatted. Is it possible to save the original email as a template and then just reference this in my code instead of creating the email here?

```
olFormatHTML = 2
olFormatPlain = 1
olFormatRichText = 3
olFormatUnspecified = 0
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "The Gap: " + str(res)
newMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML    #or olFormatRichText or olFormatPlain
newMail.HTMLBody = xxxxxxxxxx
newMail.To = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
newMail.Send()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open the template email to get html in it

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")  
template_mail = outlook.OpenSharedItem(<template email path>)
template_html = template_mail.HTMLBody
```

and then put it into newMail

```
newMail.HTMLBody = template_html
```